# Can't receive FCM Push Notifications for iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to use the Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) SDK to send push notification to iOS devices. I created a very simple application which has  an empty ViewController and an AppDelegate copied by that provided in the [quick start iOS project](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/master/messaging/MessagingExampleSwift/AppDelegate.swift#L160-L165).

I followed all the instructions provided in the [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client):

Installed SDK using pod, here is my podFile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'

target 'fcmPushTest' do
# Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use 
dynamic frameworks
use_frameworks!

# Pods for fcmPushTest

end
```

- Added the push notification in the "Capabilities" Tab in Xcode
- Generated APNs authentication key and APPID (the APPID was automatically generated by Xcode) on the apple developer portal
- Created a new project for my application in the Firebase developer console, downloading and copying the GoogleService-Info.plist file in the root directory of the project
- Uploaded the APNs authentication key in the Firebase developer console
- Installed the app and put it in background (notifications do not appear when app is in foreground)

When the application starts, it correctly returns an FCM token. Then I use this token in the FCM push notification console in order to send a message but nothing happens: notification is not received even if the console says that the message has been "completed"
[image]

Trying to send the notification with curl

```
curl -X POST --header "Authorization: key=<API_ACCESS_KEY>" \
--Header "Content-Type: application/json" \
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send \
-d "{\"to\":\"<YOUR_DEVICE_ID_TOKEN>\",\"notification\":{\"body\":\"Yellow\"},\"priority\":10}"
```

I obtain the following response:

```
{"multicast_id":7144776975498650143,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1510221288971805%7fe9e2a37fe9e2a3"}]}
```

Since success is equal to 1 i guess that all is ok but I still get no notifications.

I googled for a possibile cause of the problem but it seems that Firebase Messaging Libraries have been recently changed (pod says I'm using the FirebaseMessaging 2.0.3 version) so i can't find a proper solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I forgot to add "Remote notification" in the "Background Modes" in the "Capabilities" tab. Now it's all working as expected.