# Firebase Cloud Messaging Not Receiving Notification (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to use Firebase Notification Composer to send a test notification to my device. I am receiving an FCM token and printing it to my console, then I am trying to send a notification to that token.

Here is what I have checked:

1) I am on iOS 12.4.1

2) I am assigning the messaging delegate

3) I am receiving the FCM token from the delegate method

4) I have verified that notifications are enabled through printing to console, and when I was prompted to allow notifications I clicked allow

5) I have verified that in the Firebase project settings there is an APNs Auth Key uploaded, with a correct TeamID and KeyID

6) The delegate method willPresentNotifications is not called when I send the test message

7) I have tried with Swizzling enabled/disabled, neither work

8) There are no errors in debug

Here is the code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import UserNotifications


@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, MessagingDelegate {
var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(named: "Splish")!
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(named: "Splish")!
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]

    FirebaseApp.configure()

    Messaging.messaging().delegate = self

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        .requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) {granted, error in

            print("Permission granted: \(granted)")
    }

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    return true
}


func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {

    print("FCM Token Is: \(fcmToken)")
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {

    print("Token is: \(deviceToken)")
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {

    print("Error is \(error)")
}
```

Comment: Have you found any solution? I am having the same problem

Comment: Me too! Any luck?

Comment: Did you explicitly set "Push Notifications" as Capability for the app target? Also, you can add "Remote notifications" as a background mode also in the app's target.

Comment: @bigranga  - The problem I had was related to my Firestore database. I had created two different databases using the same ID, and that had caused problems. I solved my issue by getting rid of the old database and re-connecting my app to the new database.

Answer (score -1):

For iOS 14.4 using Swift, I used Firebase's example [here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/1fcb1525af414cc09d5a6981a320f3f50ed7ace2/messaging/MessagingExampleSwift/AppDelegate.swift).

With the help from @C6Silver suggesting to enable "Push Notifications" in Capabilities, I was then able to receive fcm test notifications.

Happy coding everyone!